# How I Pass parameters from View to Controller In Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @session = Session.new 
  end

  def fetch
    #@user = User.session(params [:user])
    redirect_to "http://www.google.com"
  end

  def create
    emai = params[:email]
    puts emai
    user = User.find_by(:email => session[:emai])

    #user = User.find_by (params [:email])
    #user = User.find_by email: 'abc@xyz.com'
    #user = User.find_by(params[:Email])

    #if (session[:Email] = user.email)
    if (user)
    redirect_to "http://www.yahoo.com"
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"

    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
      redirect_to "http://www.google.com"
    end
    #redirect_to "http://www.yahoo.com"
  end
end
```

every time i execute my view i get redirected to google.com even though i pass the parameters.

---

Edit by R Peck:

***My logic should send people to Yahoo if the params are set, but still sends to Google, how can I fix this?***

Comment: Your methods redirects to google that why everytime method fires, it will redirect you to google.

Comment: even though i am passing params in view to is not reflected in controller, it shows email is null what should i do for that.

Comment: please try `user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])`

Comment: how are you passing `email` or any `params` to the server/controller?

Comment: Started POST "/session/creater" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-28 08:28:07 +0000
Processing by SessionController#creater as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"PMQLqNQNXh9rB+SECDqyX4P46bTnO
R3SOs5jNLflYFY=", "sessions"=>{"username"=>"pratik", "email"=>"abc@xyz.com"}, "c
ommit"=>"Signup"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` IS NULL
 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://www.google.com
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: still passing email as NULL

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 user = User.find_by(:email => params[:sessions][:emai])
```

You are not getting the value of email if you only call `params[:email]` you should call parent first before calling the child `params[:sessions][:email]`.

Answer (score 0):

Several things wrong with your code.

Here's what I'd write:

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @session = Session.new
   end

   def create
      email = params[:sessions][:email]
      user = User.find_by email: email

      url    = user ? "google" : "yahoo"
      colour = user ? "valid" : "invalid"
      notice  = user ? "You signed up successfully" : "Your form is invalid"

     redirect_to "http://#{url}.com", notice: notice, color: colour
   end

   private

   def session_params
      params.require(:session).permit(:session, :params)
   end
end
```

---

**OOP**

I think this may be a little advanced but I'll write it anyway, for my own benefit.

Rails is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (it's built on Ruby which is an OOP language). This means that each time you create/call a controller, it should be centered around *objects*.

A good example for you would be the [`Devise` controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise).

This has a `sessions_controller` which essentially allows you to [CRUD (Create Read Update Destroy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) a *session*. This is the correct way to use a controller.

*Your* implementation seems to be dealing with a *user*, rather than a session, and as such you'd be best using a `users_controller` to fix it:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @user = User.new
   end

   def create
      @user = User.new
      @user.save
   end
end
```

Having said that, it does seem that you're probably going to resolve the issue to make it so that you can use the `User` to build a new session.

I guess it's best to remember that you have to ensure you're able to appreciate a good structure for your application